# Is it possible to listen to the ':host'-Pseudo-Selector?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to get the resize event of my host. I need the host size because on the left side of my app is a navigation which is visible or hidden. So I thought I will listen to the host. Is this possible?

I have already tried something but I need to know the host width and not the whole width of the window like below.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event: any){
  console.log("Width: " + event.target.innerWidth);
}
```

Comment: `resize` events are only for window-likes. Those are windows and frames. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event And those are fired only, when the window is resized, not when an element is resized

Comment: can you post your html structure. How I understand it, it could also be done with pure css.